# Openshift - How to get current memory usage of POD List

Tags: openshift, redhat, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I want to see current memory usage of PODs. I tried "oc get pods | grep elastic-*" to get POD details

```
elastic-index-5-kwz79                                       1/1       Running   0          1h
elastic-index-5-lcfzp                                       1/1       Running   0          1h
elastic-master-0                                            1/1       Running   0          1h
elastic-master-1                                            1/1       Running   0          1h
elastic-master-2                                            1/1       Running   0          1h
elastic-query-2-wspl5                                       1/1       Running   0          1h
```

Table is showing status and last running details but I am looking for current memory usage and total memory details

For Example -

```
Name                          Total Memory         Available Memory
elastic-index-5-kwz79           1024MB                723MB
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check your pod's cpu and memory usage using `oc adm top pods` as follows.
Refer [Viewing Pods](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/managing_pods.html#viewing-pods) for more details.

```
$ oc adm top pods
NAME                         CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
hawkular-cassandra-1-pqx6l   219m         1240Mi
hawkular-metrics-rddnv       20m          1765Mi
heapster-n94r4               3m           37Mi
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check pods cpu/memory usage without installing any third party tool then you can get memory and cpu usage of pod from cgroup.

1. Go to pod's exec mode `kubectl exec pod_name -- /bin/bash`
2. Go to `cd /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu` for cpu usage
   run `cat cpuacct.usage`
3. Go to `cd /sys/fs/cgroup/memory` for memory usage
   run `cat memory.usage_in_bytes`

NOTE: This usage is in bytes.